# jQuery lightbox plugin change apperance of my wordpress site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I just installed the [jQuery Lightbox Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jquery-lightbox-balupton-edition/) on my wordpress blog. But that totally changed the apperance of my menubar. Before, it was about 40-50 px high and contained my menu links, but after the installation the menubar - that is, the background of the menubar - is now only ~5-10 px high. The links are still the same height and changes background color as they should have. The problem is that the background is not containing them anymore.

**before:**

[Before http://img86.imageshack.us/i/picture3b.png](http://img86.imageshack.us/i/picture3b.png)

**after:**

[After http://img223.imageshack.us/i/picture2bqn.png](http://img223.imageshack.us/i/picture2bqn.png)

My, very unproffessional guess is that it might be css related - that the css of the plugin somehow replaces the css of my theme. I tried to check through the css of the plugin, but all the fields are named lightbox-... and i definatelly dont have anything like that on my site... so, I'm dumbstruck.

Hopefully someone at SO can help a fellow out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a CSS issue. I see on your site the css:

```
#navback {
    background-color: #121621;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 1%;
}
```

change that to this:

```
#navback {
    background-color: #121621;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

and you should be golden :)

Comment: Thanks. Your Golden!
I thought I had some reason for putting 1% there. (maybe to fix some ie thing? - Im just starting to learn css and all that so.. )
Anyways thanks a bunch!